# is it possible for the UK English upside-down option?

Tags: input-language

i know that we have Facebook UK English upside down version and i have seen images of people with Ubuntu upside-down English as well does anybody know where to get it or how to get it. thank you.

Comment: *wonders why you want upside down text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't Ubuntu related, but ǝɹǝɥ: http://www.fliptext.org/

There's also http://rotateme.org/ to show a whole web page rotated.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe what you are looking for is possible (well it's technically possible, as seen on Facebook, but I very much doubt the Ubuntu developers will implement it!)

You can however change the entire display to be upside down in System->Preferences->Monitors and change *Rotation* to *Upside Down*.

[image: Screenshot of Monitors Preferences]

(Note my screenshot is a little diferent because I have two monitors.)